# Зачем нужны такие ПО как MAMP, OpenServer и т.д

Tags: java, сервер

Объясните, пожалуйста, что такое MAMP, OpenServer. Как они работают? Для чего нужны?
Недавно столкнулся с такими понятиями и нигде не могу нормальную инфу найти. Читал, они нужны для того, чтобы поднять локальный сервер, но есть же tomcat. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: И как вы на Tomcat собираетесь PHP и MySQL запускать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Множество программ работают на сетевых взаимодействиях и можно как писать свое приложение, которое будет слушать определенный порт на компьютере и отвечать, так и воспользоваться сторонними приложениями со своими плюсами и минусами.

Особенности OpenServer и MAMP в том, что туда входят уже настроенные для локальной разработки экземпляры различных баз данных (mysql, postgres, etc...), так и настроенный на работу с PHP файлами сервер Apache HTTP Server, и все это с удобным интерфейсом (можно включать или отключать различные части). По факту просто размещается в каталоге папка с проектом и сервер автоматом перенаправляет файлы с расширение *.php интерпретатору PHP и дальше результат его работы пользователю.

Вообще Apache HTTP Server и nginx очень часто используется напрямую и настраиваются на работу с определенным языком и даже входят в сам Tomcat. Многие языки реализуют свою собственную функциональность: Ruby on Rails, Django Python, Kestral C# и т.д. и могут работать без стороннего сервера, при этом сохраняя возможность работать с Apache, Nginx, IIS в качестве прокси сервера после определенной настройки.

Особенность Tomcat в том, что он настроен на работу с сервлетами Java и для работы с другими языками его нужно будет долго и нудно перенастраивать. Тогда зачем таскать за собой Tomcat ради Apache сервера, если можно взять готовый и настроенный сервер без лишнего, да еще и с крутыми дополнениями? Так же помимо Tomcat есть и другие Java сервера со своими плюсами и минусами: WildFly, GlassFish, WebSphere.

Поэтому да, не все так просто, как кажется. Учитывая, что я и так написал уже много текста, но затронул только маленькую вводную часть без конкретики, не упоминая ничего важного и без реальных примеров различий.